# In blender game engine, add object actuator compared to using scene.addObject?

Tags: blender

In blender game engine, what are the advantages to using the add object actuator compared to using scene.addObject?

I know there is something about threading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can't give you an answer for the threading question. 
But if you want to know more:

Usually it can be a (little) performance difference. 
But it is casedependent. If you want to spawn an item by pressing a key it is better to do it with bricks, because they are faster in most cases.

But i would never go for a minimal performancewin and a big sacrifice in the workflow. scene.addObject in a pythoncontroller gives much more flexibility. You can keep the reference and add different behavior right after spawning.
Imagine you have a shattered Window and are spawning broken Tiles instead of the original window plane. If you just spawn them it is boring. You should give each tile a starting speed and rotation. With scene.addObject you can achieve that! With an actuator you would have to programm individual logicsetups in a state for a starting behavior. Tons of work, more than a little bit performance you may win. My Performancetest did not show a big difference though.

Good luck! i hope you find the answer.

Comment: Well, you can do all that without the addObject actuator, using
Added= Bge.logic.getCurrentScene().addObject('object',TargetObject,time)

Then Added = the new game object.

Like 

Added.localLinearVelocity.y = own['chargeUp']

So this negates the usefulness of using python to manipulate the add object actuator...

Hmmmmm.....